# Get the Creation Date of a PDF file using iText 7

Tags: vb.net, date, pdf, itext7

I have to create a tool which adds to several .pdf file names their creation date.
I'd like to use the creationdate stored internally in pdfs and for this I downloaded iText Community Edition.

Now, my code starts like this (VB)

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim filename As String = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)

        Dim PDFReader = New Pdf.PdfReader(filename)
        Dim PDFDocument = New Pdf.PdfDocument(PDFReader)

        Dim documentinfo As Pdf.PdfDocumentInfo = PDFDocument.GetDocumentInfo

        Dim author As String = documentinfo.GetAuthor
        Dim creator As String = documentinfo.GetCreator
        Dim mypdfobject = documentinfo.GetPdfObject

    End Sub

End Module
```

I got the GetAuthor and GetCreator together with several other Get method, but I can't find something like GetCreationDate, only AddCreationDate.

If I go further into mypdfobject I find into map a /Creationdate tag, so I thought to use that, but, while it is often in the format D:20160704132234+02'00', sometimes I find something which seems binary data and I don't know how to decode that.

Is there any better way to get the creation date ?

Thanks

Stefano

Comment: The creation date is a PDF string value. There are two ways to represent a string. You already know this way: `(D:20160704132234+02'00')`, but there's also a hexadecimal notation, for instance: `<443A32303136303730343133323233342b303227303027>`. Does the latter look familiar to you when you say *I find something which seems binary data and I don't know how to decode that*?

Comment: You should show your code for your sentence "If I go further into mypdfobject", so that others can learn from it.

Comment: Also, your code does not compile at "Dim mypdfobject = documentinfo.GetPdfObject"

Comment: @tmighty Unfortunately the question is more than 6 years old. 5 years ago `PdfDocumentInfo` stopped being derived from `PdfObjectWrapper<PdfDictionary>` and so lost the `GetObject` method...

Answer (score 4):

The creation date is a PDF string value. There are two ways to represent a string. You already know this way: `(D:20160704132234+02'00')`, but there's also a hexadecimal notation, for instance: `<443A32303136303730343133323233342b303227303027>`.

When you have a `PdfString`, you can get the value in different ways: there's `toString()`, but there's also `toUnicodeString()`. When you have a `String` version, you can get a `Calendar` object from the `PdfDate` class:

```
Calendar date = PdfDate.decode(s);
```

If you want the date in W3C format, you can do something like this:

```
string w3cDate = PdfDate.getW3CDate(s);
```

Comment: In Visual Studio, while debugging, I find

Comment: Value {�%�܌���NR��q��} (this is the binary form I say)

Comment: content {Length=16}, so it's 16 bytes

Comment: indirectReference Nothing

Comment: state         0  (i don't know the meaning)

Comment: So it's not similar to the hex string you mention.

Comment: It might be encrypted, since there is that suspicious decryptInfoNum 18