# Parsing PDF dates when they are specifed as Hex strings

Tags: c#, pdf

I am writing a parser for PDF files. Dates, such as the *CreationDate* entry of the *Info* object are supposed to be specified as text that looks something like the following:-

```
(D:20190416162204+10'00')
```

This is easy to parse and I my parser handles them just fine. But there are occasional PDF files that seem to specify dates using the Hex string format, like this:-

```
<4B230449BFB5E413CB9C81A2F132EBB0DE>
```

The PDF specification makes no mention of allowing this format. If you convert the Hex pairs into ASCII it does not transform in the previous format. Anybody come across this format for dates and know how to decode it?

Comment: What is a date equivalent for that?

Comment: (D:20190416162204+10'00') = 2019/04/16 16:22:04 +10:00

Comment: I mean the hex one.

Comment: @SeM he doesn't know, hence why he's asking...

Comment: @IanKemp Idk, OP was asking how to parse that, that's different when you don't know whether it's a date or not. I thought he can somehow see that date (but can't parse).

Comment: @PhilWright Also please add a code example of how you parsing pdf files.

Comment: I know how to parse stuff. What I do not know is the specification of the hex format. What does the hex mean? Is it binary representation of a Unix date? Is it Base64 of a string? Etc.

Comment: @PhilWright what you use iTextSharp?

Comment: Also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425925/get-the-creation-date-of-a-pdf-file-using-itext-7).

Comment: @PhilWright Is your PDF probably simply encrypted and you have not decrypted the date string yet?

Answer (score 1):

After more investigation it turns out that dates and strings can be encrypted and it needs to be decrypted correctly before being treated as the final string. The /Trailer of the PDF has an /Encrypt indirect reference and this needs processing in order to setup your decryption routine.

Answer (score -1):

It actually happens that PDF string are in hex,  but in your case it seems that the string is wrong (maybe it was created with a sloppy pdf generator)

Comment: After more investigation it turns out that dates and strings can be encrypted and needs to be decrypted correctly before being treated as the final string.